# How to push a table in another table by ascend sorting withput using sort or asort?

Tags: javascript, php

what i want to do is that i want to rewrite te table in another table by sorting it
I TRIED THESE TWO WAY AND SO MANY WAY BUT IT SEEMS NOT WORKING , HOPE YOU GUYS CAN HELP

```
$data = [3, 4, 54, 7, 9, 34, 5, 6, 7, 3, 5];

$res1 = [];


for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

    for ($l = 0; $l < count($data); $l++) {
        if ($data[$l] < $data[$i]) {
            array_push($res1, $data[$l]);
            array_shift($data);
        }
    }

}


for ($s = 0; $s < count($res1); $s++) {
    echo $res1[$s] . ' / ';
}
```

Comment: First, DON'T SHOUT! Second, elaborate what tables are you using. You mean HTML table or DB table? Share clear examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP built-in sort function

```
<?php $arr = [8,7,17,3];
$sortedArr = sort($arr);
echo $sortedArr; ?>
```

There are a lot of variations of sort you can learn about them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp)